# How to set up nginx to take up cloudfront url instead of the proxy pass for the backend server?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have set up AWS Cloudfront Distribution for streaming objects from one of my S3 bucket. After generating urls, I am able to stream. Now since I have a server running in EC2 and my web app is backed by Nginx with already configured proxy_pass for the backend server. Now how do I use that generated cloudfront url for files to start playing them in my web  app.

I am totally new to nginx following things I have tried

here is my nginx server config

```
server {
            listen       8888;
            server_name  localhost;
}

        location /app{
          alias  /opt/mw_web_app;
          index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #Create proxy_pass for DataService.
        location /service/{
            proxy_pass http://server-ip:9003/;
            proxy_set_header USER-IP $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

}
```

Comment: So , after a lot of try I found very easy to implement solution, added below to my nginx config:   location /cloudfront/{
            proxy_pass https://d9sd0w6qf9lch.cloudfront.net/;

        }

Answer (score 2):

First fix your confguration and move the second curly brace to the end . then allow your server to be default server to assign all requests to this server

```
server {
            listen       8888;
            server_name  localhost default_server;


        location /app{
          alias  /opt/mw_web_app;
          index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #Create proxy_pass for DataService.
        location /service/{
            proxy_pass http://server-ip:9003/;
            proxy_set_header USER-IP $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

second, you sould use cloud front url direclty or assign CNAME using your own domain. if you use CF through your nginx CF will be useless with extra fees.

Answer (score 0):

After a try and going to through Nginx Docs : Following worked for me and I a able to stream using cloudfront :

```
server {
            listen       8888;
            server_name  localhost;
}

        location /app{
          alias  /opt/mw_web_app;
          index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #Create proxy_pass for DataService.
        location /service/{
            proxy_pass http://server-ip:9003/;
            proxy_set_header USER-IP $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
        #Create proxy_pass for DataService.
        location /cloudfront/{
            proxy_pass https://ddddddddd.cloudfront.net/;

        }
}
```

PS: thanks @Ahmed Abdelazim for your time and yeah there was a syntax error also which u pointed out